# My site is not displayed in the Google search list

Tags: javascript, python, django, indexing, sitemap

I just uploaded a site with Django on pythonanywhere and it was indexed by Google and it is displayed in the English search list, but it is not displayed in the Persian search list.
This is my website link: https://peshgaman.pythonanywhere.com/

```
I registered my site in google search console and also created a sitemap for my site
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and type in your domain on the top bar in Google Search Console. There you will see if your site has been indexed and everything from the Google Database about the specific domain you requested. If not indexed you can request the crawler to crawl your site. Then your site is getting on the Google Search.